# pygame vs wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, pygame

I am trying to implement a game of tetris in python and am wondering which of wxpython or pygame is better to go with. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wxpython is primarily used for developing window-based user interfaces. Putting a game together using it would be pretty hackish, I think. Pygame is, of course, specifically made for game creation, so it will be a better bet.

Some other projects you might want to look into are: http://arcticpaint.com/projects/rabbyt/
and: http://www.pyglet.org/ — I personally found Pyglet to be a better library than Pygame for doing small game prototypes.